# jQuery end() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Calling end() pops the last item off the jQuery stack, so

```
$("div")
```

returns the same thing as

```
$("div").children().end()
```

I can't see in the debugger any difference with what is returned, but I noticed

```
divs1 = $("div")
divs2 = $("div").children().end()
console.log(divs1 == divs2) // false
```

Why are these two objects not equal to each other?  Is there some kind of unique identifier for objects in javascript like there is in Ruby?  Or is there something I can't see in my console that differentiates the two?

Comment: You're comparing two objects, so they are not the same even if they contain the same elements, as they are not the same object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While getting jQuery objects via selector jQuery wraps the result everytimes in a new object. So the targetting objects are identical, the wrapping jQuery objects aren't.

You should compare the DOM nodes directly this way:

```
console.log(divs1[0] == divs2[0]) // true
```

(with `...[0]` can the first node be accessed)